# Searching for a simple proof of the following integral being zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Is there any simple way to see that the following integral
$$\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sin^2(x-y)\sin^2(\alpha-\beta)\sin(x-\alpha)\sin(x-\beta)\sin(y-\alpha)\sin(y-\beta)\ dxdyd\alpha d\beta$$
is $0$?

Comment: Have you tried using the angle difference formulas?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern I strongly suspect you can do it using symmetry and perhaps the fact that sin() is an odd function. Maybe try showing the integral of the negative of this must be equal to the integral itself, and thus zero.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the identity $\sin(a-b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) - \sin(b)\cos(a)$ to try to isolate variables. Combine this with the following theorem on multiple integrals;

$$\int_a^b \int_c^d f(x)f(y) dxdy = \int_a^b f(y)dy \int_c^d f(x)dx$$

This will work since you have constant coefficients. If you can find any one of those four variables for which you can isolate an integral equal to 0, that will do it.