# Solve the following integral $\iiint \left(x+y+z\right)\left(x-y-z\right)\left(x+y-z\right)dV$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Hello there I am looking how to solve this integral

$$\iiint \left(x+y+z\right)\left(x-y-z\right)\left(x+y-z\right)dV$$

using change of variable under the following planes:

$x\:+\:y\:+\:z\:=\:0$

$x\:+\:y\:-\:z\:=\:0$

$x\:-\:y\:-\:z\:=\:0$

Please give some advices to do solve it or any hints you have in mind...

Thanks

Comment: There is the problem that these three planes don't enclose a volume, in fact 3 planes in 3d never will, just like how 2 lines in 2d will never enclose an area.

Comment: Find a few duplicates ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367836/sum-of-vandermonde-determinant?noredirect=1), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222400/searching-for-a-simple-proof-of-the-following-integral-being-zero?noredirect=1)) using [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Ciiint%20%5Cleft(x%2By%2Bz%5Cright)%5Cleft(x-y-z%5Cright)%5Cleft(x%2By-z%5Cright)dV%24&p=1)

Comment: What is the domain of integration?

Answer (score 0):

Multiply out the polynomial and integrate each term to find:

$$\frac{1}{6} x y z \left(2 x^2-2 y^2-3 y z-2 z^2\right)$$

Comment: should be a comment. please refrain from one-liner answers in the future.

Comment: It isn't a comment.  It shows the *solution*.